# Cómo generar links y verlos en html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Cómo hago para generar diferentes links o enlaces que tengo y verlos en código HTML? Por ejemplo con estos links:

```
https://ejemplo1.com 
https://ejemplo2.com 
https://ejemplo3.com 
https://ejemplo4.com 
https://ejemplo5.com 
https://ejemplo6.com 
https://ejemplo7.com
```

lo que quiero es que se genere automáticamente de esta forma tal como está, así:

```
<a href="https://ejemplo1.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO1</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo2.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO2</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo3.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO3</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo4.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO4</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo5.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO5</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo6.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO6</strong></a>[/spoiler]
<a href="https://ejemplo7.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO7</strong></a>[/spoiler]
```

Estuve buscando mucho por la web alguna información pero no encuentro alguna solución.

Comment: Buen día, cómo tienes guardados esos enlaces? en un array?...

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el código que has intentado utilizar o lo que has investigado hasta ahora.

Comment: hola, no esta en un array, solo los tengo en editor notepad++

Comment: Si guardas los links en un array, sería más beneficioso para obtener lo que deseas, ya que con tenerlo en un array, podrías acceder a ella, iterarla y mostrar los resultados en el HTML con un for.

Comment: Nada tiene que ver tu editor (Notepad++) con que esté en un array o no. ¿Estás queriendo realmente decir que tenés los enlaces _en un archivo de texto_?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener los links guardados en un array e ir iterando cada posición del array para concatenarlo en una cadena, así formarías tu etiqueta y con un diferente enlace (ya que cada enlace sería cada posición del array), por ejemplo:

```js
let arrLinks = [
  'https://ejemplo1.com',
  'https://ejemplo2.com',
  'https://ejemplo3.com',
  'https://ejemplo4.com',
  'https://ejemplo5.com',
  'https://ejemplo6.com',
  'https://ejemplo7.com',
];

// obtengo al div donde mostraré los resultados.
let texto = document.getElementById("enlaces");

for (let i = 0; i < arrLinks.length; i++) {
  // ingreso a cada posición del array por cada bucle del for.
  let link = arrLinks[i];
  // luego, lo que obtenemos de dicha posición del array, lo concatenamos en la cadena y almacenamos en la variable "resultado".
  let resultado = '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong> EJEMPLO' + (i + 1) + '</strong></a><br>';
  // y por último, mostramos la cadena completa en el div, en donde sería un enlace distinto por cada bucle.
  texto.innerHTML += resultado;
}
```

```html
<div id="enlaces"></div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo que necesito es que los enlaces que los tengo en notepa++ https://ejemplo1.com quiero que se muestre en codigo html y dentro de esta linea de codigo <a href="https://ejemplo1.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><strong>EJEMPLO1</strong></a>[/spoiler]

Comment: Yo creo que no se entiende muy bien que es lo que quieres, porque lo que te explicó @Cris223511.dev esta perfecto. Deberías aclarar bien entonces